# Squared linear differential operator meaning

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, differential-operators

What does the linear differential operator, $Q$, defined as

$Q = (1 + \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d}{dt})^2$

mean exactly? That is, in the context of ODEs.

Does it mean the following?

$Q = 1 + \frac{2}{\alpha}\frac{d}{dt} + \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$

or this?

$Q = 1 + \frac{2}{\alpha}\frac{d}{dt} + \frac{1}{\alpha^2}(\frac{d}{dt})^2$

Comment: What's the difference between the two possibilities you gave?

Comment: Are they defined as equal? I might've thought that $(\frac{d}{dt})^2 f = (\frac{df}{dt})^2$ and not  $(\frac{d}{dt})^2 f = (\frac{d^2f}{dt^2})$.

Comment: If that were the case, the operator wouldn't be linear. Think of it as a matrix, $A^2x$ is not $(Ax)^2$, the first is a product of operators, the second a product of vectors. In this case $A=\frac{d}{dt}$, and $A^2$ simply means "do $A$ twice"

Comment: Ah, yes.. of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means applying the operator twice. Remember, $1$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ are not simply numbers, they are operators, so you can't just multiply them that way (at least, usually you can't). Here it works out since all the operators commute.

To your question, that just looks like different ways of writing the same thing, since $\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^2$ is simply differentiating twice with respect to $t$, as is $\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\right)$. Again, it's just notational conventions.

Comment: Thank you! I thought you could multiply them out, so thanks for making that clear.